# Block access to folder and allow only from subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

I got a folder called roundcube and also a subdomain called webmail.domain.org. I add this code in .htaccess to block accesing to domain.org/roundcube and allow only on webmail.domain.org.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.domain\.org$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^roundcube/$ http://webmail.domain.org [L,NC,R=301]`
```

Accesing domain.org/roundcube still works and webmail.domain.org gives me this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, me@domain.org and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is there really a ` mark after the `[L,NC,R=301]` or is that a typo?

Comment: There is a `, not a typo :)

Comment: Have you tried to remove that from your .htaccess rule?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't worked too.